# How to mock a database connection in c#?

Tags: c#

I am having difficulty mocking DbConnection. How do i mock a concrete object?
I have inherited some legacy code, so I can't refactor the code at the moment. 
The code works but it is slow, because i need to have an actual database connected when doing tests.
What are my options with the current code as it stands?

I would typically do `mockedInstance = Mock<Interface>();` and pass that the mock object to the controller.

```
Task<bool> IAdmin.CreateAccount(Request request)
{
       using (var conn = DbConnection(SQLSettings))
       {
             try
             {
                // if query passed
                return true;
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                // if query failed 
                return false
             }
       }
}

private SqlConnection DbConnection(string connString)
{
      // open connection
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
      conn.Open();
      return conn;
}
```

Comment: Is the above your controller code ?

Comment: Instead of mocking you can just wrap your tests in a transaction and use an MDF

Comment: Could you mock `IAdmin.CreateAccount` instead?

Comment: @auburg yes it is.

Comment: @Lee I do that when i'm testing at a higher level.

Comment: All that code should not be in your controller - your controller code should be as thin as possible and simply be calling a service (i.e. a class that handles saving / getting to a database) that implements an interface. That interface is injected into your controller and then can be mocked in your tests.

Comment: I would switch to Entity interface instead of SQLClient.  Entity is much faster and puts data directly into DB classes.

Comment: @jdweng Unit tests shouldn't be doing any database calls, whether through SQLClient or EF

Comment: Once you generate the classes for Entity then the Unit Test will be able to fill the classes as part of testing.

Comment: @jdweng Not without using external libraries such as this https://entityframework-effort.net/

Comment: Aren't the entity classes accessible to c# code?